# Can I attach to a service and debug it in AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

I compile my own AOSP Android images.
In AndroidStudio, is it possible to attach to a service i.e. to the SystemServer process and debug it (similar to gdb's *attach*)? If it is not possible in AndroidStudio, is there some other native debugger that I can use for the symbolic debugging of a java service?

Comment: Can you just attach from the Android Studio debugger?

Comment: I did a ```mmm development/tools/idegen &&  development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh``` and importet the android.ipr. Now I have the AOSP sourcetree in AndroidStudio. 
I dont see any option to attach to i.e. system_server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it.

You could attach to any process by select [Run > Attach Debugger to Android process]

[image: Attach Debugger to Android process]

[[image: Choose Process2]

Comment: when ```mmm development/tools/idegen &&  development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh``` and importing ```android.ipr``` there is no "debug configuration" set and therefore the "Attach Debugger to AndroidProcess" is not selectable.